# How to manipulate this csv, in py especially, while i insert one Character like psg, and the result is 9

Tags: python-3.x

This is the example csv. I already tried another way but still print useless things, i just want to get the values (Count).

[image: Img]

Answer (score 0):

You can just read through pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'FILE.csv')
print(df['Count'])
```

If you need to print only the Counts:

```
print(*df['Count'].values.tolist(),sep="\n")
```